# Vectorized operation on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have the following code which goes through each row of a dataframe and assigns the prior row value for a certain cell to the current row of a different cell.

Basically what im doing is finding out what 'yesterdays' value for a certain metric is compared to today. As you would expect this is quite slow (especially since I am working with dataframes that have hundreds of thousands of lines).

```
for index, row in symbol_df.iterrows():
    if index != 0:
        symbol_df.loc[index, 'yesterday_sma_20'] = symbol_df.loc[index-1]['sma_20']
        symbol_df.loc[index, 'yesterday_roc_20'] = symbol_df.loc[index-1]['roc_20']
        symbol_df.loc[index, 'yesterday_roc_100'] = symbol_df.loc[index-1]['roc_100']
        symbol_df.loc[index, 'yesterday_atr_10'] = symbol_df.loc[index-1]['atr_10']
        symbol_df.loc[index, 'yesterday_vsma_20'] = symbol_df.loc[index-1]['vsma_20']
```

Is there a way to turn this into a vectorized operation? Or really just any way to speed it up instead of having to iterate through each row individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be overlooking something, but I think using `.shift()` should do it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print df

#         Date    SMA_20    ROC_20
# 0  7/22/2015  0.754889  0.807870
# 1  7/23/2015  0.376448  0.791365
# 2  7/22/2015  0.527232  0.407420
# 3  7/24/2015  0.616281  0.027188
# 4  7/22/2015  0.126556  0.274681
# 5  7/25/2015  0.570008  0.864057
# 6  7/22/2015  0.632057  0.746988
# 7  7/26/2015  0.373405  0.883944
# 8  7/22/2015  0.775591  0.453368
# 9  7/27/2015  0.678638  0.313374

df['y_SMA_20'] = df['SMA_20'].shift()
df['y_ROC_20'] = df['ROC_20'].shift()
print df

#         Date    SMA_20    ROC_20  y_SMA_20  y_ROC_20
# 0  7/22/2015  0.754889  0.807870       NaN       NaN
# 1  7/23/2015  0.376448  0.791365  0.754889  0.807870
# 2  7/22/2015  0.527232  0.407420  0.376448  0.791365
# 3  7/24/2015  0.616281  0.027188  0.527232  0.407420
# 4  7/22/2015  0.126556  0.274681  0.616281  0.027188
# 5  7/25/2015  0.570008  0.864057  0.126556  0.274681
# 6  7/22/2015  0.632057  0.746988  0.570008  0.864057
# 7  7/26/2015  0.373405  0.883944  0.632057  0.746988
# 8  7/22/2015  0.775591  0.453368  0.373405  0.883944
# 9  7/27/2015  0.678638  0.313374  0.775591  0.453368
```

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere. Kindly accept the answer if it helped you. Good luck! (I see you're doing some trading there!)

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't allow me to accept the answer earlier. I think there's a minimum time. But yes, I trade full time. Thanks again for the help.